# iOS SDK: Moving the button into the center of screen by code

Tags: ios, button, sdk, position

I want to move a button to the center of the screen by code. I saw somewhere it is just few lines of code, but could not find them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do it:

```
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - yourButton.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - yourButton.frame.size.height/2, yourButton.frame.size.width, yourButton.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: this seems to work well for portrait but not for landscape, am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 23):

This centers the button in its superview:

```
CGRect bounds = button.superview.bounds;
button.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
```

Comment: Isn't this the equivalent of `[button setCenter:superview.center]`?

Comment: Nope, `center` is measured in the superview's coordinate system, so that would set the button's `center` to the middle of its superview's superview.

Answer (score 2):

Here is more simple approach:

```
yourButton.center = self.view.center;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! Use center.x or center.y for specifics in x or y if needed!

Comment: how do you make this support orientation changes? :(

Answer (score 1):

Both rooster117 and DavidNg answers seem correct. Just to add one more "option" to you, if you want to do this animated, you should do:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = 1.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:seconds animations:^{
    //here you should write any reframing/repositioning code
}];
```

Comment: hi Bruno, what if I want a button to animited with a specific colors, red and while for instance?

Comment: Just put the color-change code inside the animation block. Something like:
    NSTimeInterval seconds = 1.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:seconds animations:^{
        [[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}];

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it without writing any code.
If you you want to try to place the button into the centre of screen by using interface settings, you can [view my clip](http://youtu.be/Swskjb_9ELQ).

Answer (score 0):

```
bntTimeEtrySave.Frame =new CoreGraphics.CGRect (
    this.View.Center.X-((bntTimeEtrySave.Bounds.Size.Width)/2),
    bntTimeEtrySave.Frame.Y,bntTimeEtrySave.Bounds.Size.Width,
    bntTimeEtrySave.Bounds.Size.Height);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/230241); please edit your answer to include at least some explanation of why it works.